# Java docker with jar load main

Tags: java, maven, grpc

Running a gRPC based Java Client Server applications in Java. I was able to generate stubs for servers but when it comes intra-service communication, I'm unable to generate stubs for the client application that happens to be a war file running in wildfly. Here's the overview.

1. **Server** -> Products (Jar running in a container)
2. **Client** -> A War file running on Wildfly

Client is exposing a rest endpoint that in turns call Server.

My understanding is that I should share the proto file between 1 & 2. Following proto is copied both to 1 and 2 under src/main/proto

```
service ProductService {
    rpc findAll(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (Product);
}

message Product {
    string id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}
```

Question. Is my understand correct to share the protocol file between two isolated applications and then communicate between the two via generated stubs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the `.proto` is fine. You could also place the generated code into a library that is shared by client and server. You could also put the `.proto` into a shared location (like a repository) that both the client and server build processes use.

Copying the proto is easy and works. You just want to make sure you know what is the "canonical" version of the proto; you want to know what version should be updated first so that you know the most recent version of the proto. You don't want both the client maintainers and server maintainers to make changes to the proto and then need to figure out how to merge the changes.

Comment: I understand the approach, how would that work in a containerized environment with `docker` and `docker-compose`, what would be the workflow? I'm trying to wrap my head around on how to share a library that's generated on the fly with both client and server containers.

Comment: I don't know enough about your docker setup to respond. You simply said "docker" one time in the subject but didn't mention any more. Copying the .protos doesn't require docker. And most client/server builds can share artifacts already through a Maven repository or similar. More specific answers change a lot depending on when and how you are building.

Comment: yes because I've never done so, I'm new to grpc and docker both of them, so you mean to say I should create a separate Module, place proto files in it, generate stubs, publish to maven repository. the client/server then links against this repo, is this the workflow?

Comment: You _can_ create a separate artifact and publish it to a maven repository, and have the client and server both use the same artifact. That is _one_ of the possible workflows.